# re-sign IPA files

Tags: ios, ipa, sign

We have IPA file which is developed by another developer with his certificates.

We are trying to re-sign the IPA which is built and distributed using another developer certificate. Please let me know if you have done this before or have any idea about this.

Tried some solutions mentioned in below links however we were able to generate IPA but can't install it in a device.

We are trying it in iOS 8. Mac 10.10.

Comment: in your particular device UDID is added on that provisional profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this software. It was working fine for me for re-signing IPA with enterprise certificates.

https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign

Answer (score 4):

Re-signing is a multi-step process which can produce errors at each step. So please have patience and try to understand each step by itself.

```
# Start with files:
# .ipa-file 'MyApp.ipa'
# New provisioning profile 'profile.mobileprovision'

# Unpack the .ipa-file
unzip MyApp.ipa

# Extract the old entitlements from the binary
codesign -d --entitlements :- Payload/MyApp.app > entitlements_old.plist

# Extract the new entitlements from the provisioning profile
security cms -D -i profile.mobileprovision > profile.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'Print :Entitlements' profile.plist > entitlements.plist
```

Now there is a manual step to edit the `entitlements.plist` so the `application-identifier` is correct. Refer to the `entitlements_old.plist` as a reference, but note that the team identifiers at the beginning of the value should be different.

```
# Then replace the embedded provisioning profile
cp profile.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision

# Re-sign the binary and update entitlements
#
# Note: replace "Firstname Lastname (TEAMID123)"
#       with your certificate name
#
codesign -f -s "Firstname Lastname (TEAMID123)" \
    --entitlements entitlements.plist \
    Payload/MyApp.app

# Create ipa
zip -r MyApp2.ipa Payload/
```

Sadly, the error messages when something is wrong do not give any special information about what exactly is wrong. But it may be:

- Wrong signing identity used
- Entitlements mismatch between the binary and the provisioning profile